# How can I set a Skybox as my background in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a Skybox I want to use and am trying to apply it to my scene. When I try to drag it to the `Hierarchy` box it doesn't work. I tried applying it to a camera like [described here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-Skybox.html), but it didn't work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You seemed to have missed something on that page, it says that

You have two options for implementing Skyboxes. You can add them to an individual Camera (usually the main Camera) **or you can set up a default Skybox in Render Settings's Skybox Material property. The Render Settings is most useful if you want all Cameras in your scene to share the same Skybox.**

So basically you just go to **Edit->Render Settings->Skybox Material->(Whatever skybox you want)**. If you want to create your own Skybox, see [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/HOWTO-UseSkybox.html). Hope this helps!

Comment: Why you talk to yourself as another person!

Answer (score 2):

Can be done by setting in **"Render Settings"**  which will be used in all cameras or else using camera settings to specific camera...

In camera u can set by **Adding the Skybox Component to a Camera** to override default Render Settings. Skybox material has a **cubemap**. And set its **Clear Flag**  to **SkyBox**